# Carousel non-repeating views

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, icarousel

I am using carousel. I have the set the type as iCarouselTypeRotary. What my issue is the images keep repeating i.e. I have 4 images only. After the last image, 1st image repeats and it continues. I want it to stop like iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2 type. Please help. I cannot use any other type. I want this style only for carousel.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try looking at the docs?  The answer was right on that page....https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will add the images in the Array.Check for the array and Maybe the following code helps you

This code is as per new iCarousel lib files

```
 - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
{
    return value * 1.1f;
}

if (option == iCarouselOptionWrap)
{
    return NO;
}
return value;
}
```

This code is as per old iCarousel lib files

```
-(BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have the images in the array itself. Where is this new iCarousel lib files.

Comment: @SwatiWadhera https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel this is the link and download the examples in that you will find new icarousel